# Search Windows Indexing Service through SQL

Tags: sql-server, database, windows, filesystems, odbc

This is more of a "just wondering" question.  Is there any way to access the Windows Indexing service database through ODBC in MS Access or SQL Server?  I know there are a million recursive programming ways to traverse the file system but if I was only looking for files with a certain name I would think something as simple as "Select Fullpath from CDrive Where FileName like '%HEVC%'" would be easier and more lightweight than other methods.

I can't seem to Google this since all it does is return a million results for ODBC DSN creation.

Comment: Well, lets start by defining what our terms mean. WIS database means what? Does sound interesting

Comment: what is the OS you are using?

Comment: Windows 10 Professional.  The windows indexing service indexes files so I assume a database is created somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, Found something else here:

[Querying the Index with Windows Search SQL Syntax](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb231256(v=vs.85).aspx)

Works like a charm, just have to get used to the special SQL syntax.  Works on Windows 10, just having a problem querying a Storage Space.  I'll update if I find an answer.

Answer (score 1):

*Foreword: My focus is on other projects, but this is an interesting topic.*

Microsoft uses an EDB file to provide a central [Indexing Service - MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee805985(v=vs.85).aspx). Based on the [Microsoft SQL Server CE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms885373.aspx) engine, it is lightweight offers a number of methods for access including addition of third party file type definitions.

However, there are differences...significant ones that prevent direct translations of EDB and CEDB. [Comparing EDB with SQL Server CE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms885305.aspx)

As I said, there are access methods. The ODBC you were hoping for was discontinued after Windows XP.

However, Microsoft has developed two methods:

- [Windows Search](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa965362(v=vs.85).aspx) (client side)
- [Microsoft Search Server Express](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=18914) (server side)

Both methods allow for quick file searches and likely could be integrated into whatever warehouse architecture you have through APIs, for example. However, there are limitations on methods that the links point out.

I admit I cannot give a full answer since I was learning, too, but hopefully this can point you in the right direction.

Cheers,

Comment: You might find these two main methods from Microsoft sufficient enough for what you are needing, though I get why you might want a warehouse implentation from using SQL Server. Sounds "pretty radical, dude", as the 90s used to say. :)

Comment: We dreamed a dream of Longhorn and got charms....  I appreciate the research, my API skills are low but once pointed in the right direction I can learn to drink the water... or at least not drown.  Thanks!